# Django-CMS page admin interface style jstree broken

Tags: jstree, django-cms

Here's how my interface looks:
[image]

I tried fiddling with the CSS but I guess there's something I'm missing and this is broken.

[Here's the code for the page](http://pastie.org/8589294).

Any clues, please?
If this is something obvious- great. Else, I'll dig in and provide more details but I have a hunch that this may be something obvious to someone smarter than me.

Comment: Have you tried "pythonX.X manage.py collectstatic" to collect all static files?

Comment: @Wirzi I'm in debug mode so I don't need to do that, right? Besides - I don't see any missing files in the browser's debug console.

Comment: No not in the debug mode. If you updated something the static files could be the same but not the content. So I would try collectstatic and if anything is fine the console will tell you.